# How to detect user selection of subtitles when using AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

When using the `AVPlayerViewController`, the user is allowed to select whether the subtitles are on a specific language, `off`, or set to `auto`. Setting the `requiresFullSubtitles` property I can force the display of subtitles, but that is not what I want.

Is there a way to detect what the user has selected for the subtitle setting, whether a language is selected, `off`, or `auto`?

[image: Now Playing Info Center]

Comment: I don't know anything about `AVFoundation`, but if it's not possible then how are you expected to switch to the correct subtitle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the currently selected language options & also grab the language info when it's used to set the subtitle or audio track, as described in "[Adding Subtitles and Alternative Audio Tracks.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/adding_subtitles_and_alternative_audio_tracks)"

Available subtitles & audio tracks are found in an array of `availableMediaCharacteristics` for the video asset.

They're grouped in an `AVMediaSelectionGroup` by whether they are `AVMediaCharacteristicAudible` or `AVMediaCharacteristicLegible` ...

The [currently selected option](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmediaselection/1389197-selectedmediaoption) is found by:

```
`func selectedMediaOption(in mediaSelectionGroup: AVMediaSelectionGroup) -> AVMediaSelectionOption?`
```

It could return `nil` so "none," or it would return whatever language is selected. So you could set up some custom 'didChange' listener on that property. Doesn't seem to be any sort of publicly available notification for this, so you'd have to make your own.

Whenever you would select/set the subtitle option on the player, you could capture and use that same information to do whatever it is you intend to do with it:

```
if let group = asset.mediaSelectionGroup(forMediaCharacteristic: AVMediaCharacteristicLegible) {
    let locale = Locale(identifier: "es-ES")
    let options =
        AVMediaSelectionGroup.mediaSelectionOptions(from: group.options, with: locale)
    if let option = options.first {

        /*** DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE AFTER CAPTURING THE LANGUAGE SELECTION  & RETRIEVING AN AVAILABLE SUBTITLE ***/ 

       playerItem.select(option, in: group)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a notification [AVPlayerItemMediaSelectionDidChangeNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritemmediaselectiondidchangenotification?language=objc) appeared in iOS 13 and tvOS 13

You can subscribe your AVPlayerItem to this notification:

```
if (@available(iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, *)) {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(handleMediaSelectionChange:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemMediaSelectionDidChangeNotification
                                           object:playerItem];
}
```

And then you can detect what language or subtitle user has selected:

```
- (void)handleMediaSelectionChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = (AVPlayerItem *)notification.object;
    if([playerItem.asset isKindOfClass:[AVURLAsset class]]){
        AVURLAsset *asset = (AVURLAsset *)playerItem.asset;
        AVMediaSelectionGroup *audio = [asset mediaSelectionGroupForMediaCharacteristic:AVMediaCharacteristicAudible];
        AVMediaSelectionGroup *subtitles = [asset mediaSelectionGroupForMediaCharacteristic:AVMediaCharacteristicLegible];
        AVMediaSelectionOption *selectedAudio = [playerItem.currentMediaSelection selectedMediaOptionInMediaSelectionGroup:audio];
        AVMediaSelectionOption *selectedSubtitles = [playerItem.currentMediaSelection selectedMediaOptionInMediaSelectionGroup:subtitles];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to know WHAT changed? In my case, I'm trying to detect only subtitles changes, but I'm assuming if you select other audio tracks for example, this would also be triggered. I can keep track of the last subtitle selected and check but that's less than ideal.

Answer (score 3):

mc01's answer is correct, but if you want a cut-and-paste solution for Swift 4, here is what is ended up with:

```
var selectedSubtitleLocale: Locale?

fileprivate func detectSubtitleLanguage() {
    var locale: Locale?

    if let playerItem = player?.currentItem,
        let group = playerItem.asset.mediaSelectionGroup(forMediaCharacteristic: AVMediaCharacteristic.legible) {
        let selectedOption = playerItem.currentMediaSelection.selectedMediaOption(in: group)
        locale = selectedOption?.locale
    }

    selectedSubtitleLocale = locale
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Swift version of @kotvaska

You can add this observer while configuring session/periodic observers

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    self,
    selector: #selector(didMediaToggle(_:)),
    name: AVPlayerItem.mediaSelectionDidChangeNotification,
    object: nil
)

@objc func didMediaToggle(_ sender: Notification) {
    print("LOGGER: mediaSelectionDidChangeNotification:", sender.description)
    let subtitles = player.currentItem?.asset.mediaSelectionGroup(forMediaCharacteristic: .legible)
    print("LOGGER: mediaSelectionDidChangeNotification: subtitles:", subtitles)
}
/// this will not be called in case of `CC`, aka only `On` and `Off` case
```

For **CC** you can give a shot to this notification as **CC(Closed Captions)** is completely [different](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/iphone/iph3e2e23d1/ios) from **Subtitles**.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    self,
    selector: #selector(didCaptionsToggle(_:)),
    name: UIAccessibility.closedCaptioningStatusDidChangeNotification,
    object: nil
)
```